# I'm getting a Compile Error but I think I have all the parts

Tags: list, vba, ms-word, contentcontrol

I have a document with a list in the list format. I tried combining two subs as you can tell in `changebullet` with `findbullet`. I'm trying to get `findbullet` to cycle through the document and go to a new list in the list index. I'm then trying to use `changebullet` to cycle through if statements to see if a string exist in the contentcontrol( i debated using `Selectcase`).

The Idea is to pick an item in the dropdown list of the content control (in this case ContentControls(1)) and then click a command button to trigger `Changebullet`. You can see my bullet list that is trying to be entered in the code. With out all the mumbo jumbo at the top of `changebullet` it generates a list just fine in the "symbol" font style.It just wont add the bullets to the list lastly it wont maintain the font of the text as "Times New Roman" it changes everything to Symbol (only the bullets need to be symbol).

I'm running into compile errors regarding for statements already in use or an error where End with is not found or end if is not found.

UPDATE/EDIT: I went through some iterations and fixed my problems. Below is the list of errors and then the list of fixes.

1. Was getting compiling errors with the suggestions of @EventHandler I was able to fix the code. (It helped to indent everything correctly in VBA so I could see the problems.
2. Unnecessarily made the code to complicated by adding to subs together.
3. Then the program wouldn't cycle correctly adding a list with no bullets only where the cursor was when running the macro.

To fix the issues

1. I took out the unnecessary sub addition, and formatted the sub so that my statements lined up with the end statement.  (easy fix)
2. Added the line `ActiveDocument.Lists(1).Range.Select` this allowed the macro to only interact with the list I was trying to manipulate "List 1"
3. To fix the bullet issues (ie. not displaying after entering the text. I set `ContinuePreviousList:=True` This allowed the text insertion to display bullets and kept List 1.

Things I took away from this miss hap. Get the Macro to either select the section I wish to interact with or get the cursor to move where I want interact with the Document. To keep the list index from breaking and to add/adjust the bullet list make continue previous list equal true.

)

```
Sub changebullets ()
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim i As Long
Dim HCE As Long
Dim CntCtrl As Variant

CntCtrl = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text
HCE = ActiveDocument.Lists.Count
With Selection
    If InStr(ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text, "DropDownItem1") Then
        ActiveDocument.Lists(1).Range.Select
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
        Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:=True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToSelection, DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
            With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
                .NumberFormat = ChrW(61623)
                .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
                .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
                .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
                .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .TabPosition = wdUndefined
                .ResetOnHigher = 0
                .StartAt = 1
                    With .Font
                        .Size = 8
                        .Name = "Symbol"
                    End With
                .LinkedStyle = ""
            End With
        Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Hello does it work yet?"
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="New Bullet Mother Trucker."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Second Bullet Mother Trucker."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Third Bullet Mother Trucker."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Fourth Bullet Mother Trucker."
    End If
    If InStr(ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text, "DropDownItem2") Then
        ActiveDocument.Lists(1).Range.Select
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
        Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:=True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToSelection, DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
            With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
                .NumberFormat = ChrW(61623)
                .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
                .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
                .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
                .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
                .TabPosition = wdUndefined
                .ResetOnHigher = 0
                .StartAt = 1
                    With .Font
                        .Size = 8
                        .Animation = wdUndefined
                        .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
                        .Name = "Symbol"
                    End With
                .LinkedStyle = ""
            End With
        Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Xtina is a well dressed Environmental Scientist."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Micah has King Ranch Chicken that he'd like to eat."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Where you ever in college."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Josh is a Madman and he has Tattoos."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Fourth Bullet Mother Trucker."

    End If
    If InStr(ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text, "DropDownItem3") Then
        ActiveDocument.Lists(1).Range.Select
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
        Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:=True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToSelection, DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
            With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
                .NumberFormat = ChrW(61623)
                .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
                .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
                .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
                .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
                .TabPosition = wdUndefined
                .ResetOnHigher = 0
                .StartAt = 1
                    With .Font
                        .Size = 8
                        .Animation = wdUndefined
                        .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
                        .Name = "Symbol"
                    End With
                .LinkedStyle = ""
            End With
        Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Dick Whitmen."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Wagner."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Gesting."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Jasmin."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Fourth Bullet Mother Trucker."

    End If
    If InStr(ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text, "DropDownItem4") Then
        ActiveDocument.Lists(1).Range.Select
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
        Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:=True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToSelection, DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
            With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
                .NumberFormat = ChrW(61623)
                .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
                .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
                .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
                .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
                .TabPosition = wdUndefined
                .ResetOnHigher = 0
                .StartAt = 1
                    With .Font
                        .Size = 8
                        .Name = "Symbol"
                    End With
                .LinkedStyle = ""
            End With
        Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Ready Mix."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Dump Trucks doing Stuff."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Mad men is a crazy show."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="The IBM computer was installed."
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Stubblefield Coddington Whinchell 3rd."

    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Mods please feel free to delete if you don't think this is worthy. @eventHandler has helped enough to get me moving through some more iterations of the above code. Still broken but i'll repost if I get a working solution or something that is closer to being correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's a `for each` you are not finishing

```
If InStr(ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text, "ISWPPP") Then


    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.ListParagraphs
```

and at the end of all

```
 End If
 Next oPara
```

Comment: Thanks for the info once I got past that compilation error I was able to work through the issue I re-posted my ammended code.